# Reading data strings from a file and dynamic resizing algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, file, dynamic, resize

Would it be best to read in from file and allocate in the bagTester function or the ArrayBag class. Basically I'm looking for some direction as what a good approach to this problem would be. I've been away from coding for awhile and just don't want to come up with some unnecessarily complex solution.

Instructions:

Using the ArrayBagSmartPointer example, extend it to include:

- Reading data strings from a file
- Accommodate dynamic resizing using this algorithm:
  Starting with a dynamic size of 10, if the number of elements exceed this number:

a. Reallocate the container size to double the current size

b. Move the contents of the current container to the newly sized container

c. Delete the previously sized container.

Repeat from step 1a. as necessary.
Note the data file called "words.txt" is in the documents folder for this week.

Link to ArrayBagSmartPointer example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5O-9XC_iL_wMk1MVmdvN1AyVEU/view

(Please let me know if there is a better way to share this code)

Comment: `Please let me know if there is a better way to share this code` - it would probably be better if it didn't require a password :)

Comment: Tell us your password